# Changing only one parameter of path in runtime

Tags: angularjs

What is the simplest way to change only one parameter of the path?

```
$routeProvider.when('/foo/:id1/:id2/:id3/', {
    templateUrl: base_url + 'foo/bar_partial'
})
```

The URL:

```
http://localhost/project/start#/foo/144/202/110
```

When the user clicks a link, only the parameter 'id2' should be affected:

```
$scope.changeParamId2 = function() {
    $location.path('foo/144/'+ng.newid2+'/110');
}
```

So, is there a way to change just the 'id2' without having to rewrite all the old path? Maybe using $route or $routerProvider?

Comment: `$routeParams['id2'] = ng.newid2?`

Comment: $routeParams change the data in model, but the changes are not reflected in the URL

Comment: Well, it looks like the only way is to create a new path from the adjusted set of routeParams, like `$location.path('foo/' + routeParams.id1 + '/' + routeParams.id2 + '/' + routeParams.id3 + '/')`. Yes, it'd be nice to have a helper method for that.